# validating user input by retrieving database contents in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to Asp.net.I created a sample application.  Its database consists of a table tUser with two fields userName and password.  When the user enters username and password and clicks the submit button, my application should retrieve contents from tUser and cross check it with user input and should behave accordingly.  What i did is this:
login.cshtml

```
@model DEntitis.Users
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Login";
int i = 0;
}
@Html.Label("Username")

@Html.TextBoxFor(user => user.UserName)
<br /><!no need to use the same name>


 @Html.Label("Password")
 @Html.TextBoxFor(user => user.Password)
<br />
<Button type="submit">Login</Button>
<a href="https://www.mail.google.com">If not a member Register</a>


<!--to store database value!-->
        @for (i = 0; i < ((Model ?? new DEntitis.Users()).UserRoles ?? new List<DEntitis.UserRoles>()).ToList().Count; i++)
        {
        @Html.HiddenFor(user => user.UserRoles.ToList()[i].UserRoleID)       
        @Html.HiddenFor(user => user.UserRoles.ToList()[i].UserID)     
        @Html.HiddenFor(user => user.UserRoles.ToList()[i].RoleID)

       }-
```

My controller action is this:
**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 12)
    {
        try
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                Users user = service.GetUserbyId(id);
                return View(user);                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Plz help...

Comment: What DMS are you using? SQL, MYSQL, Access???

Comment: database i am using is sqlserver express2005

Answer (score 0):

It is required to have @using (Html.BeginForm ) on top of your view.

That will by default post data to the current URL of the browser with post method.

Hope this helps.